# Map does not correctly detect colors with geopandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm creating a map with geopandas whose colors are determinated **by some conditions**. However, my code is not working properly in relation to colors: red, yellow and green. This that I've tried:

```
def color_mapping(row):
    if row['pedidos_venta'] > 10000:
        return 'green'
    elif row['pedidos_venta'] > 2000:
        return 'yellow'
    else:
        return 'red'


mapa_pedidos_venta['color'] = mapa_pedidos_venta.apply(color_mapping, axis=1)
mapa_pedidos_venta.plot(column = 'color')
```

Nevertheless, my result is this:
[image]

I don't understand why the color range is different from the one I provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom color map using the `ListedColormap` and plot it along with the 'color' column:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap



def color_mapping(row):
    if row['pedidos_venta'] > 10000:
        return 'green'
    elif row['pedidos_venta'] > 2000:
        return 'yellow'
    else:
        return 'red'


mapa_pedidos_venta['color'] = mapa_pedidos_venta.apply(color_mapping, axis=1)
mapa_pedidos_venta.plot(column = 'color')

# create a custom color map
cmap = ListedColormap(['red', 'yellow', 'green'])

# plot map using 'color' column and custom color map
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
mapa_pedidos_venta.plot(column='color', cmap=cmap, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```